# Swift. How to dynamically divide results into several parts

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, flickr

I'm new to iOS development and for my current app I need to do the following:

- get results from Flickr search (done)
- write results to array by 10 items (can't figure out how)
- populate results in collection view by 10 items

so, here's what I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var start_btn: UIButton!
fileprivate var searches = [FlickrSearchResults]()
fileprivate let flickr = Flickr()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    flickr.searchFlickrForTerm("cat") {
        results, error in

        if let results = results {
            print("Found \(results.searchResults.count) matching \(results.searchTerm)")
            self.searches.insert(results, at: 0)
```

So, instead of the last line I want to split results (that has 500 records) into batches of 10, so that later I can source them batch by batch from searches array.

Can you tell me if this is a good idea and how to achieve it?

Comment: Are you just trying to do paging? - show a page of 10 results at a time?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is there a easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Any one of the solutions below should work, you just need to modify them to use your searches array.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is good idea. To split your array later you can use two variables - `startIndex` and `endIndex`. For example if you want to show only records from 0 - 9 indexes, write something like:

```
startIndex = 0 
endIndex = 9

let resultsBatch = results[startIndex...endIndex]
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! Can you help me to figure out how can I fill array searches in a loop with resultBatches?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple Swift 4 extension to `Array` to chunk an array.

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(by size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map { index in
            Array(self[index..<Swift.min(index + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

In your code, you will want to store all the results, then only show the page you are interested in.

```
@IBOutlet weak var start_btn: UIButton!
fileprivate var chunkedResults = [[FlickrPhoto]]()
fileprivate var searches = [FlickrPhoto]()
fileprivate let flickr = Flickr()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    flickr.searchFlickrForTerm("cat") { results, error in
        if let results = results {
            print("Found \(results.searchResults.count) matching \(results.searchTerm)")
            self.chunkedResults = results.searchResults.chunked(size: 10)
            self.searches = self.chunkedResults.first ?? []
```

Comment: I really like this approach, problem is that 'result' is not an array and can't by chanked. Can I chank searches?

Comment: @TuesdayFourAM It looks like you need to dig into results to get the array of `FlickrPhoto`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it within creating an array which has inside array lists. Please find below an example code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var start_btn: UIButton!
// Make a array list which can store arrays of FlickrSearchResults
fileprivate var searches = [[FlickrSearchResults]]()
fileprivate let flickr = Flickr()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    flickr.searchFlickrForTerm("cat") {
        results, error in

        // Prepare some section / counter / insideArray varaibles to split your values
        var section = 0
        var counter = 0
        var insideArray = [FlickrSearchResults]()

        if let result = results {
            if counter < 9 {
                // Fill the inside array list, if we reach 10 values, they will be stored in your searches array list
                insideArray.append(result)
                if result == results.last {
                    // If you identify the end of your values
                    searches.insert(insideArray, at: section)
                    continue
                }
                counter = counter + 1
            } else {
                // Store the first 10 values in your array list section [0], then the next 10 values in section[1], etc.
                insideArray.append(ar)
                searches.insert(insideArray, at: section)
                counter = 0
                section = section + 1
                insideArray = []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Thing is that results is not an array and it doesn't allow array methods

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful:

```
    let resultsCount = 505
    let batchSize = 10

    var startIndex = 0
    var endIndex = 0

    let batchesCount = Int(results.count / batchSize)
    let batchRest = results.count % batchSize

    var batches: [[Int]] = []

    for batch in 0..<batchesCount {
        startIndex = batch * batchSize
        endIndex = startIndex + batchSize

        batches.append(Array(results[startIndex...endIndex]))
    }

    let lastBatch = Array(results[endIndex..<endIndex + batchRest])
    batches.append(lastBatch)

    print(batches)
```